# How to share a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot

Could you give me a tip? I created a REST endpoint in Spring Boot. It was a task for the interview. The solution uses my local address. Now I must share the solution with the employer. Considering that he does not have Spring Boot, Tomcat etc., how can I share it to make it easy to run my application for the employer ?

Comment: you can export your project as a jar file and then your employer can execute that jar file using command line. Here is a link that will show you the steps on how to do that https://www.concretepage.com/questions/510

Comment: In my experience when Employer asks to share your code with them public github repo is what they want. You can go extra mile and deploy your app on some VPS, but main thing they want to see is your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Virtual Private Server (VPS) for easy deploy and maintain. Many VPS are Linux but if you're not familiar with Linux (Ex. CentOS / Ubuntu) command line. You can try Windows VPS. I suggest a 1 year free trial with Linode, Amazone Webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the Spring Boot app to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) following this [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) and push your code to [GitHub](https://github.com) or [GitLab](https://gitlab.com). Make sure to provide a `README.md` file with list of available endpoints and instructions on how to test your app's functionality. You can then share both the link to the GitHub repository and the URL of the Heroku app with the employer.

Tip: You can rename the domain Heroku generates for you with `heroku rename <new-app-name>`. Note that  the free Heroku apps are put to sleep after a period of inactivity. The apps only wake up when a web request is made. Make sure to explain the employer a certain delay is expected when they test the endpoint as the app uses Heroku's free tier.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy ur application e on cloud and provide the rest APIs to customers.